# What is the keyboard shortcut for Exposé on Mac OS X ?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, expose

I am trying to find/change shortcut for expose'.  Other docs refer to an option in Keyboard Shortcuts to change "Expose and spaces".  Where are these on os x 10.8.4?  As can be seen in screenshot they do not reside directly in Keyboard shortcuts settings:

[image: Keyboard shortcuts does not include expose]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`Exposé` is referred to as `Application Windows` in the Keyboard shortcut preference window, and `App Exposé` in the trackpad preference window.

To activate it press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and  <kbd>down arrow</kbd>

You can verify that they are in fact the same thing just with different names by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and  <kbd>down arrow</kbd>  and observing that it has the same behavior demonstrated in `App Exposé` of the Trackpad preference pane (4 finger swipe down )

I get the impression that App Exposé is moving the way of the dodo because App Exposé came unchecked by default on my 10.8 install. (Also,  Mission Control is just so much more useful than Exposé)

[image: towards]

Answer (score 2):

In addition, I was confusing Exposee (what is now called Application Windows) with Mission Control, which displays a flyout of running apps on the current Desktop, a list of desktops across the top, and the dock.  Set your keyboard equivalent for Mission Control, which I am used to doing the 4-finger up-swipe from the touchpad.

I actually came across this thread because I am using [Synergy 2](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) to remotely control my Mac, from a PC with a standard PC keyboard.  The "CTRL-1", etc. settings in System Preferences actually translate to Alt-1, etc. from the PC keyboard.

Comment: I am using Synergy 1, and in the config for each remote client, the key remapping could solve it.